# You installed esbuild on another platform than the one you're currently using

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile, svelte

I am trying to containerise Svelte js app inside a docker container and I am getting this error on the log complaining about esbuild in a different platform , I am using M1 mac, I have tried to install `esbuild-wasm` as what the log suggested and tried `npm i esbuild-linux-arm64` as a step in the docker file and tried `RUN npm install yarn` as the log suggested yarn as it have built-in stuff deal with the platform but it didn't work
my docker file

```
FROM node:16.10.0
WORKDIR /my-website
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

the error is

```
You installed esbuild on another platform than the one you're currently using.
This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.

Specifically the "esbuild-darwin-arm64" package is present but this platform
needs the "esbuild-linux-arm64" package instead. People often get into this
situation by installing esbuild on Windows or macOS and copying "node_modules"
into a Docker image that runs Linux, or by copying "node_modules" between
Windows and WSL environments.
```

Comment: What's actually running `esbuild` (are you missing a `RUN npm run build` line from the Dockerfile)?  Do you exclude the host's `node_modules` directory in a `.dockerignore` file?  Are you getting this error while building the image or running the container, and if it's running, are you replacing the image content with `volumes:`?

Comment: I am getting the error when I run docker-compose up --build
my docker-copmose file
```
version: '3.8'
services:
  rad-website:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/my-website
      - /my-website/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 32):

You've copied `node_modules` from your local environment to the container. Locally you have packages for the darwin-arm64 arch, but inside the container, it is a Linux system that requires packages for linux-arm64.

To avoid such errors you should not copy node_modules to the container.

All you need is to add node_modules to `.dockerignore` file

Comment: DOH! can't believe I made this mistake as well.. Google brought me here.

Answer (score 11):

I deleted `node_modules` and run `npm install` to re-install `node_modules` and it fixed

Comment: hi, 

first of all thank you for taking time to add your answer although,
the correct answer is the one with `.dockerignore` missing the node_modules.
also if you add a code snipet, your answer will standout and you will earn more reputation

Comment: When I pulled down a repo that had node_modules already, I ran into the problem OP has, where I was trying to run esbuild x64 code on an M2 Mac. Your response fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in my react app.. but I was using docker compose and even though i added the .dockerignore file to my setup, it did not work out as

###### I had a volume linked to automatically reload the changes...

so in case you have the same issue..
make sure that you dont include "node_modules" directory by selectively choosing the files you want to mount..

root directory structure

```
project/
    |-- docker-compose.yaml
    |-- frontend/
        |--Dockerfile
        |--README.md
        |--index.html
        |--node_modules
        |--package-lock.json
        |--package.json
        |--public
        |--src
        |--vite.config.js
    |-- backend/
        |--Dockerfile
        |--server/
```

compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: bgt_frontend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    # to make changes dynamically without reloading docker compose
    # this part caused the issue... 
    # since i had my node_modules in the frontend directory 
    # so it was also mounted to the container..
      - ./frontend:/app
```

Fix:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: bgt_frontend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    # to make changes dynamically without reloading docker compose
    # add the directories or files one by one such that "node_modules"
    # is ignored via .dockerignore.
      - ./frontend/src:/app/src
      - ./frontend/index.html:/app/index.html
```

The above logic worked for me.. hopefully it works for you as well in case u run into it..

Comment: Worked for me :) And thanks for the before and after files with clear comments

Comment: It worked for me too! Thank you for taking the time to help the community 

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth for anyone running into this without Docker, I had the same issue with an M2 Mac running a node process until I ran:

`node -p "process.arch"`

Where it then returned "arm64"

After which I nuked my node_modules, ran npm install, and voila!

Full article on the fix: https://blog.hao.dev/fixing-esbuild-related-cpu-architecture-error-on-apple-silicon-macs

Answer (score 2):

I received a very similar error to this when moving my code to a new computer. All I had to do was run `npm install` and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I found my node version manager was defaulting to the x64 binary, so I had to reinstall and specify arm64.

e.g.
`fnm install --arch=arm64 16`

Answer (score 0):

My issue (using m1 Macbook Pro) was both my terminal and Node version was x86 (rosetta) instead of arm64. This worked for me:

1. Make sure your terminal is using arm, right click terminal app, get info and uncheck rosetta. Verify by typing "arch" in terminal, you should see "arm64"
2. Ensure your node is also using arm by typing "node -e 'console.log(process.arch)'"
3. remove your node modules and install again.

all thanks to this guy: https://gist.github.com/LeZuse/bf838718ff2689c5fc035c5a6825a11c