# Node, Laravel and Vite: You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using

Tags: node.js, laravel, vite

I'm getting the following error after upgrading node to v18 when running `npm run dev` in a fresh laravel install (v9) that uses vite:

```
You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139649/you-installed-esbuild-on-another-platform-than-the-one-youre-currently-using-th), but I'm not using docker. I have no clue what this means and what to do...

Comment: Are you using a mac with an apple chip?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have upgraded node, you need to reinstall packages. Simply do npm i in your project. If that does not work, delete your node_modules folder and retry.