# npm run build works locally but not off of a docker image

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, vite

I'm trying to dockerise a basic Vite React app and am getting an error I don't understand:

```
 => [builder 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                 37.6s
 => [builder 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                         0.5s
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                          1.5s
------
 > [builder 6/6] RUN npm run build:
0.589
0.589 > frontend@0.0.0 build
0.589 > tsc && vite build
0.589
1.529 ✘ [ERROR] Cannot start service: Host version "0.18.15" does not match binary version "0.18.16"
1.529
1.529 1 error
1.534 failed to load config from /app/vite.config.ts
1.534 error during build:
1.534 Error: The service was stopped: write EPIPE
1.534     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1083:25
1.534     at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:703:9)
1.534     at afterClose (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:693:28)
1.534     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2142:11
1.534     at onwriteError (node:internal/streams/writable:418:3)
1.534     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     RUN npm install
   5 |     COPY . .
   6 | >>> RUN npm run build
   7 |
   8 |     FROM nginx
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
 
FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I'm simply trying to containerise a build to serve with nginx as part of a Docker course.

I don't recognise the version numbers described in the error: host 0.18.15 versus binary 0.18.16. These are not version numbers for Typescript or Vite (the CLI tools invoked with npm run build), nor are they Node - I'm running Node 19.1.0 at present and tried using different Node images in the Dockerfile.

I'm unsure how to proceed further as regards a fix. I also had previously tried building in WSL but was running into a different issue.

Comment: I assume COPY . . may be copying in some cached files if you haven't set up a .dockerignore that excludes them. Since you haven't installed with a package lock, it could cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @J.Titus is right. `COPY package*.json` (note the asterisk) to include your package-lock.json, add `node_modules` to a `.dockerignore` in the same directory as the Dockerfile (probably project root), and if you want, only `COPY` over the actual relevant files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You installed esbuild on another platform than the one you're currently using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139649/you-installed-esbuild-on-another-platform-than-the-one-youre-currently-using)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.  Forgot my tsconfig.json